# 'content-disposition' on iOS+GoogleChrome [Flask on Google App Engine]

Tags: python, ios, google-chrome, google-app-engine, flask

I'm a beginner in coding. I would like to make a simple web application using Google Cloud Text to Speech API.

1. a web site with a text box
2. you input a sentence in the text box and click a button "submit"
3. you can download a mp3 file which is made by Google Cloud Text to
   Speech API

I'm an English teacher in Japan, so I would like my students to use this website to improve their English pronunciation.

Firstly, I'd like to show you my code.
I use Flask on Google App Engine standard environment Python3.7.

This is directory structure.

```
.
├── app.yaml
├── credentials.json
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

This is main.py.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import send_file
import os
from google.cloud import texttospeech

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form['text']

        os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="credentials.json"

        client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
        input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(text=text)
        voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(
            language_code='en-US',
            name='en-US-Wavenet-A')

        audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(
            audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)

        response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)

        # The response's audio_content is binary.
        with open('/tmp/output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
            out.write(response.audio_content)

        return send_file("/tmp/output.mp3",as_attachment=True)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>practice pronunciation</title>
        <style>
            #text {width: 100%; height: 300px;}
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Let's practice pronunciation!</h1>
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <textarea id="text" name="text" placeholder="Type some text here..."></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is requirements.txt.

```
Flask==1.1.1
future==0.18.2
google-cloud-texttospeech==0.5.0
grpcio==1.26.0
gunicorn
```

This is app.yaml.

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

---

When I accessed my app through PC(Google Chrome on Windows10),it worked perfectly. However, when I accessed my web app from iPhone10(Google Chrome), download didn't start.

From PC Chrome:

Step1: If I enter my app's URL on browser(Google Chrome on Windows10), I see this simple form.
[image: form]

Step2: I input a text and push "submit".
[image: submit]

Step3: Download mp3 file to the local download folder.
[image: download]

From iPhone10 Chrome:

Step1 and 2 are same as PC Chrome

Step3: Download doesn't start. I want the mp3 file to be downloaded on "Files" app(iPhone's native file manager application).
[image]

I thought this is a problem of 'content-disposition', so I searched "content-disposition on iOS". However, I couldn't get an answer.

Could you give me any information or suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, Kazu

Comment: Is this behavior exclusive to Chrome on iOS? Have you tried to use another browser on the phone in order to test it?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, rsalinas. I tried Safafi and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Safafi instead of Chrome and it worked perfectly!

Comment: I did a little digging, and this seems to be an issue with chrome on iOS. I even found some [bugs](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=794206) from way back, but bottom line, the issue is not your code but chrome for iOS. I suggest you take a look around [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) if you want to report this issue again or if you want to find any resolution offered to others who experienced the same behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much for detail information, rsalinas. I opened Chromium forum you suggested, but I am so beginner that I don't know what to write there. Excuse me. Anyway, I know that Safari does download mp3 file that my app offer. It's OK. Students will use Safari to access my app. Now I'm interested in Chrome on Android. I haven't tested whether 'content-disposition' on Chrome on Android works well.

Comment: Glad to be of help. According to the forums I read, this issue doesn't happen on Chrome for Android. Nevertheless, you should check before telling them to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your information! I'm glad to hear that and I will check with an Android phone.